# Any known, verified examples of sabotage of a launch vehicle bound for orbit?

Tags: launch, rockets

Are there any known and verified examples of sabotage of a launch vehicle destined for Earth orbit or beyond?

...or at least widely regarded as 'very likely'? Attempted but unsuccessful examples could count if they came really close. Rock throwing wouldn't count for example.

Sub-orbital launches are excluded, as they could be weapons delivery (actual or tests) and sabotage could be considered self-defense. "Pilot error" type events are also excluded. I'm asking about things like this:

[image: Gary Seven]

**above:** Screen shot or file photo from the Star Trek original series episode *[Assignment: Earth](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Assignment:_Earth_(episode))*, (#20, Season 2) where [Gary Seven](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Gary_Seven) is sabotaging a rocket launch. This is the only image of rocket sabotage I could find, but this kind of thing wouldn't count for this question as it was a sub-orbital launch. Photo [from here](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Assignment:_Earth_(episode)).

Comment: Hard to prove a negative, but I'm certainly not aware of any. Sabotage could explain things like the Polyus launch, but Hanlan's Razor makes simple accident a much more likely explanation.

Comment: You ruled it out so posting as a comment, but the slave laborers building V2s committed sabotage when they could http://www.v2rocket.com/start/chapters/mittel.html

Comment: There sevral suspicions of sabotage on Ariane and Proton, but nothing officially confirmed

Comment: @OrganicMarble That's a good point and a good reminder - thanks for the link.

Comment: Regarding the photo - why are movie Bad Guys always associated with cats?

Comment: @Andy there is a link, follow it and read further before you make value judgements.

Comment: Props for a photo of Gary Seven and Isis.

Comment: Gary Seven's more or less a good guy, not a bad guy. http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Gary_Seven

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A speculative example for the [Proton](https://www.rt.com/news/165024-proton-booster-sabotage-investigation/) can be found. 
This incident is apparently not a closed case, but it is the best I could find.
According to [TASS](http://tass.com/russia/697388) 3 of the 6 angular rate sensors were installed upside-down, and according to sites which do not seem to list their sources (so I have not linked them) the sensors are very hard to install upside-down, but that is conjecture as far as I'm concerned because I cannot find any good sources for that data.

Comment: Stay tuned for breaking news any day... they're closing in on [Johnny Depp](https://theringer.com/ranking-potential-saboteurs-of-elon-musks-spacex-venture-ff66e7e2b23f#.9b3lmvt6b) now! :-)